# Malloc and Paging

Tags: virtual-memory

When a user process invokes malloc(n), are there any physical pages allocated to the process? I believe No since malloc allocates from the heap. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Linux, I believe the short answer to your question is "usually no physical pages are allocated". This is called "[memory overcommit](http://www.etalabs.net/overcommit.html)" and you can find [tons](https://superuser.com/questions/200387/linux-overcommit-memory) of [documentation](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting) on it. Unix variants have had different policies about actual physical page allocation at malloc-time. 4BSD-based systems traditionally did not overcommit, which in combination with the `chill` program (can't find a reference) was endless fun. `chill` allocated and held as much memory as it could. Because SunOS (4.2BSD-based) always allocated physical pages for any `malloc()`, a mere user could allocate all RAM and cause everyone else to page endlessly.

For linux you can find out what your system's policy is: `cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` should give out a "0", "1" or "2" with the meanings "heuristic overcommit", "always overcommit" and "never overcommit" respectively.

Comment: Does malloc allocate from the heap?

Comment: Also are physical pages allocated once you have started to write to the memory allocated by malloc?

Comment: @user100503 - Yes, malloc()/calloc()/realloc() allocate from the heap. A little-used function alloca() allocates on the stack, but it's easy to make mistakes with alloca(). I believe that writing to an allocated page causes the kernel to actually allocate the physical memory. I can't point at any code or anything, but I'm still pretty sure.